# Website works in firefox but not in chrome or safari. Navigation row does not line up correctly in chrome and safari

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome, safari

Below is my code for my website. It works perfectly on firefox but not in chrome or safari. The only thing that doesn't work is the navigation row displays to the right of the header picture and the home button is the full length of the header picture. I think it has something to do with the display:inline in the css but I'm note sure.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Workouts</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id = "page">
            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="border" width = "50%" height ="100%">
            <div id = "header">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src =images/header_logo2.png />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </div>
                <tr class = "nav" height="30px" width="100%">
                    <td></td>
                    <td><a href="index.html">Home</a></td>
                    <td><a href="about.html">About</a></td>
                    <td><a href="workouts.html">Workouts</a></td>
                    <td><a href="trainers.html">Trainers</a></td>
                    <td><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></td>
                    <td></td>


                </tr>
                <tr class = "content" width="100%">
                    <td><img  width="100%" src="images/content.png" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my stylesheet

```
* {
    margin-top:0;
    padding-top:0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
body{
    background:pink;
}
.border{
    background-color: #c92f51;
}
.nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:pink;
}
.nav a:hover{
    color:gray;
}
.nav td{
    display: inline-table;
    width: 14.29%;
    height="30px";
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    color:pink;

}
tr .content{
    background:#c92f51;
}
.content td{
    background:white;
    padding: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every table row has to have the same number of columns. If you don't, you need a `colspan` attribute to make up for it.

Also you should not have `<div>` tags directly instead a table. How browsers handle these types of errors is not very consistent, so it's best to fix them. Try changing:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="border" width = "50%" height ="100%">
            <div id = "header">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src =images/header_logo2.png />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </div>
```

To

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="border" width = "50%" height ="100%">

            <tr id = "header">
                <td colspan="7">
                    <img src =images/header_logo2.png />
                </td>
            </tr>
```

And also add the same colspan on the last row:

```
<tr class = "content" width="100%">
                    <td colspan=7><img  width="100%" src="images/content.png" /></td>
                </tr>
```

More generally, using tables for layout like this is not good practice nowadays. If you search google for "css layouts vs tables" you can find out a lot more about it.

Comment: I changed the colspan to 7 and got rid of the div but that just made things worse. Everything became different sizes and spread out all over the place. Once i fix this problem I will research css layouts and attempt to fix that but for now I need to at least get this fixed.

Comment: I figured it out...i needed to add colspan to the bottom column as well.

Answer (score 2):

Invalid mark-up without `DOCTYPE` declaration. Check your code by copy/paste in [w3c validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) check the errors.

Answer (score 1):

Use [a validator](http://validator.w3.org/). Your HTML is invalid and at least one of your errors causes significant differences in how different browsers error recover from it.

Some will move the `<div>` that is a child element of the `<table>` so it is outside the table (because it isn't allowed there).

You don't have any tabular data in there, so get rid of all the table markup and use something more appropriate (e.g. a list for your list of links and so on).